# Adding Expect-CT header to HTTP response

Tags: certificates, header, certificate-transparency

In the security test report, I have a recommendation to add Expect-CT header to the HTTP response from web application, additionally developers set this to:

`Expect-CT: max-age=0, report-uri=`

I am not sure if it is a good idea to add this header. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect-CT:

"The Expect-CT will likely become obsolete in June 2021. Since May 2018 new certificates are expected to support SCTs by default. Certificates before March 2018 were allowed to have a lifetime of 39 months, those will all be expired in June 2021."

So because certificates are expected to support SCTs by default I do not think that this header makes any sense.

When it comes to configuration according to https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-expect-ct/ `max-age=0, report-uri=` means:

"This policy is deployed in report-only mode and if the browser doesn't receive CT information that it's happy with, referred to as not being 'CT Qualified', rather than terminate the connection it will simply send a report to the specified report-uri value."

Because I don't have uri here, the report will not be sent, so there is no additional security at all.

On the other hand I see that some popular websites like Linkedin still use this header, the example from Linkedin:

`Expect-CT: max-age=86400, report-uri="https://www.linkedin.com/platform-telemetry/ct"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because I don't have uri here, the report will not be sent, so there
> is no additional security at all.

You are right.

In case `enforced` is not specified, as in your case, and browser detects a CT violation, e.g. because a mis-issued certificate is used or because of misconfiguration of your web site, it makes sense to report it to the web site owner. Then, if the problem was caused by misconfiguration, the owner has a chance to fix it. In your case the URI is empty, it means the problems will not be reported to you. In your case, the `enforce` flag is not specified. This means, in case of problems browser will still establish connection. Thus, as you said, such usage of `Expect-CT` has no additional security.

In case `enforced` is specified, the browser will refuse connections to the host. In such cases, even if URI is empty or means a non-existing endpoint, there is still a value: Browser will warn the user and will refuse connections that are insecure.

> additionally developers set this to:
>
> `Expect-CT: max-age=0, report-uri=`

Because of the reasons above, this makes no sense.

> So because certificates are expected to support SCTs by default I do
> not think that this header makes any sense.

From the user perspective, both SCT and `Expect-CT` (with `enforce` flag) will prevent insecure connections. But if `Expect-CT` uses a URI to report problems, it can be easier for the owner to be informed about the problems. Otherwise it make take a long time until you get informed that some users experience problems when connecting to your web site, and may be even stopped visiting it.

But what is the probability that you mis-configure certificate? See details below.

> On the other hand I see that some popular websites like Linkedin still
> use this header ...

I suppose Linkedin wants to be informed about the cases when browser believed that CT was violated, e.g. a mis-issued certificates were used or web site was mis-configured.

**To use or not to use?**

I have no statistics about what percentage of users face any CT problems and how many of them are caused by CA, how many otherwise valid certificates are not registered in the log, or if there are any CAs that issue especially many certificates without proper registration in the log. That's why I cannot decide for you if you should use `Expect-CT`.

I would suggest that you try first to rely on SCT only. Depending on [how CA delivers SCT](https://www.digicert.com/faq/certificate-transparency/enabling-ct.htm), some configuration of web server may be needed. Then use some online service to do a detailed test of certificate configuration of your web site. There are many such services. It is up to you which one to prefer. After you fixed any issues that such service has found, you can assume that for the most users it will work well and thus `Expect-CT` will not have any considerable additional value.